# how to get controller name from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Url is :

**https://localhost/caseTest/index.php/c_case_type_questions/master/c_case_type_questionset/id/1**

I need to get **c_case_type_questions** from above url,
Is there any way to get it in short way?

Comment: $this->uri->segment(3); // or 4. I think it will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL class’s function

```
$this->uri->segment(n); // n=1 for controller, n=2 for method, etc
```

for more detail follow this URL

https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-uri-segment/

Comment: Why should one do so? Please add some explanation, such that others can learn from that code

Comment: @NicoHaase what do you mean `why should one do so?` its pretty understood that this is a method to get the controller name from the uri. 
in that function they breaks the part of the uri separate the domain and get the first chunk after exploding the slashes to obtain controller, clear now?

Comment: Sorry, to me that is not obvious. In which context is `$this->uri` set to anything? I've worked with tons of code that even have no variable `$uri` within their classes. And if it is so simple to explain, please add some of that explanation to your answer. It helps future reader understand what your code does

Comment: Please don't link to external pages - put all of your answer here

Comment: @NicoHaase are you sure about what you said? we are talking about codeigniter here right? and CI has a library for urls, by loading this library in auto load its accessible in whole project. `uri->segment` will work pretty much everywhere in classes, models, helpers etc so i am not sure what else do you need to be explained here

Comment: Just imagine you would start today working with CI and looking for something like in the question - would you like to have some short answer or something longer from which you can learn more?

Comment: for me if i want to know more about the pre defined function i can dig into the code as its open source.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the PHP "Magic Constant" `__CLASS__` which, if evaluated in the controller, will return the controller's class name.

I'm not able to check this next idea at the moment and might not be remembering correctly, but I believe `$this->router->class` should also return the controller's name. The `router` class is loaded during the framework's startup and it stores both the class and method names as properties of the class.

Answer (score 0):

On your Controller,

```
public function myController(){
        $data['controller_name'] = $this->router->fetch_class(); //this is currently holding your controller name

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('my_directory/page', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

If you want the name of your controller displayed on your view, create a folder in your CI view folder with the name my_directory with file in it page.php and write the code below inside.

```
<?php echo $controller_name; ?>
```